# Repeat a terminal command

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, terminal

Suppose I have a terminal command called `foo` (in reality this would be something like `cd` or `ls` or something more complicated.  Is there a way that I can perform this command numerous times WITHOUT the use of a script.

For instance, I want to do the equivalent of the following:

```
foo && foo && foo && foo && foo
```

Is there some way that I can do something along the lines of

```
foo * 5
```

or maybe

```
5:foo
```

I'm using a linux machine.

Comment: In addition to `for`, you could use `watch`, as mentioned in this [StackOverflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13593771/linux-repeat-command-automatically)

Answer (score 1):

Add some semi-comma into blogger's answer to make it as one-liner:

```
for variables in {1 2 3 4 5};  do ls; done
```

Answer (score 1):

blogger is right. however, it's important to note the syntax exactly:
if you're using an interactive shell (e.g. the terminal)

```
echo -n; for i in {1..5}; do if [[ $? ]]; then foo; fi; done
```

the "$?" returns the status of the previous function call; because we're calling "echo" first, the first iteration of the loop will be "true" (0 in bash.) the "fi" closes off the "if" statement, and the semicolons are necessary.

here's the same thing if you were writing a bash script:

> #!/bin/bash
>   echo -n
>   for i in {1..5}; do
>   if [[ $? ]]; then
>   foo
>   fi
>   done

you'll notice that foo doesn't have a semicolon after it; when writing a full-blown bash script in an environment where line-breaks are available (e.g. your favorite text editor,) line-breaks do the same thing as semicolons :)

also, note that you could instead use

```
[[ $? ]] && foo
```

instead of the if statement; realize that the && means that foo will only be executed if the previous foo didn't have an error. i.e. in the function call

```
thing1 && thing2
```

thing2 will only be executed if thing1 runs fine (technically, if it returns a 0 value)
to ignore whether foo is working or not, use semicolons instead of &&

Answer (score 1):

You can try something like:

`for i in {1..10}; do YourCommand; done`

Example:

`for i in {1..5}; do ls -l; done`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using "for" loop?

```
for VARIABLE in 1 2 3 4 5 .. N
do
    command1
    command2
    commandN
done
```

Comment: When I try to do that, it just brings up a new line that says `for>`

Answer (score 0):

I found a great method [here](http://www.stefanoforenza.com/how-to-repeat-a-shell-command-n-times/).

I know it's still "kind of a script" but i think it's the closest you can get without typing a whole command line with commands.

You can create the command `repeat` with which you can do this:

```
 repeat 5 ./foo
```

Add the following lines to the end of your `~/.bashrc` (if you're using bash):

```
repeat() {
    n=$1
    shift
    while [ $(( n -= 1 )) -ge 0 ]
    do
        "$@"
    done
}
```

and the next time you login (or start bash) you can use `repeat 5 ./foo`.

Btw. `repeat` is already a keyword (which does exactly the same) in csh, tcsh and zsh, so with this addition you will add it to `bash` and it will work exactly the same.